# How to rename certain files in all subdirectories in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, file-rename

I have the main directory as Topics and within that I have sub-directories and sub-sub directories. The sub-directories are like `Beta_0.00`1, `Beta_0.002`, `Beta_0.005` and `Beta_0.01`.

Each of the sub-directories have sub-sub-directories like `Iter_100`, `Iter_500`, `Iter_1000`.

I have four file names which contain special symbols. For example:

```
Aviva_buys_US_insurer_for_?1.6bn.txt
```

I want to rename this file as `Aviva_buys_US_insurer_for_1.6bn.txt`. Similarly the other files with special symbols by removing the special symbols.

I tried using :

```
find . -type f -exec mv Aviva_buys_US_insurer_for_?1.6bn.txt Aviva_buys_US_insurer_for_1.6bn.txt {} \;
```

But this is not working. How do I fix this? Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `find` command is doing nothing, as the `mv` command contains a static file name.  You want something which finds files with funny characters (where we don't really know without more information what *exactly* you mean by "funny") and then runs `mv` on each of the found file names.

I can't think of a simple way to generate the file name without the funny character without spawning a subshell, so let's simply pass all the found files to a subshell which does a loop and generates the new names.

My "funny" expression contains a fairly restricted set of "unfunny" characters, and considers everything else as "funny".  You might want to extend it with some more characters (maybe you want to keep `:` and/or `!` and/or `+` etc etc; though make sure you keep `-` as the first character after the `!` negation operator).

```
funny='[!-A-Za-z0-9_./]'
export funny  # Make this variable visible in the subshell we spawn, too
find . -type f -name "*$funny*" -exec bash -c 'for f; do
    mv "${f}" "${f//$funny/}"; done' _ {} \+
```

This uses the Bash string interpolation `${variable//from/to}` to substitute all occurrences of "funny" characters; and the `find -exec \+` to pass as many found files as possible to a single subshell.  If your `find` does not support this, you will need to refactor.

This is not completely robust -- if the file name consists solely of "funny" characters, the substitution will produce an empty file name, which isn't allowed (though if the path is valid, it will be moved onto itself, which is harmless, as such).

If you want to experiment, change the `mv` to `echo mv` and play around.  When you see results you like, change it back.